# Why reference const can be re-assigned in for-statement?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, and I'm confused about this:

```
vector<int> v = { 1,2 };
const int &r1 = v[0];
//r1 = v[1];  // compiler will show error.
```

I understand that reference const `r1` cannot be re-assigned. But look at the codes below:

```
for (const int &r2 : v) cout << r2;
```

Why wouldn't that go wrong? The reference const `r2` is assigned twice, right?

Comment: It is assigned to v[0], then to v[1], isn't it?

Comment: Why is `for(int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {const int &r1 = v[k];}` allowed?

Comment: @immibis I read that as if it was a [koan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%8Dan), and was enlightened. :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No it's not assigned twice. `r2` exists from the start of the iteration (a single round over the loop body) until the end of the iteration. `r2` in the next iteration is another object by the same name. Each iteration has their own `r2` and each of them is initialized separately.

Comment: But `r2` is a const. The book I read said that `r2` is a low-level const, whose value can not be changed. Am I right?

Comment: @XunChenlong Please read the answer more carefully before commenting. The answer already addresses your comment. :)

Comment: @hvd Oh, I got it. One iteration means one loop. I mistook it as the whole for-statement. It helps. Sorry for my poor English and thank you!

Answer (score 24):

According to the C++11 standard **[stmt.ranged]**:

```
for (const int &r2 : v) std::cout << r2;
```

where ¹`v` is a `vector`, is equivalent to:

```
{
    auto && __range = (v);
    for (auto __begin = __range.begin(), __end = __range.end(); __begin != __end; ++__begin)
    {
        const int &r2 = *__begin; // <-- new variable in each iteration
        std::cout << r2;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bf7f579656c358c)

> The reference const `r2` is assigned twice, right?

No. There is a *new* `r2` variable in each iteration.

---

<sup>¹ The range based `for` can also be used with other kinds of collections, including raw arrays. The equivalence given here is what the general equivalence becomes for a `std::vector`.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

The ranged-based `for` looks like this:

> attr(optional) for ( range_declaration : range_expression ) loop_statement

where *range_declaration* is

> range_declaration     -   a declaration of a named variable, whose type is the type of the element of the sequence represented by range_expression, or a reference to that type. Often uses the auto specifier for automatic type deduction

So each iteration a new declaration is introduced, the reference only exists until the next loop iteration.